# How to add a listener to edit text box?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listener

I am creating a GUI in Matlab with some data being updated dynamically. The update is being printed in a edit text box.

Is there a way to add a listener to the edit box so that the program can react at anytime when the edit box is being updated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way and conveniently it's called `addlistener`. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html).

Basically you can listen for a change in any property which makes it very useful.

Example:

```
fig = figure();
text = uicontrol('Style', 'edit');
lh = addlistener(text, 'String', 'PostSet', @callback);

function callback(source, event)
disp('Ouch!');
```